# How can I prevent users from editing the OpportunityLineItem records in Salesforce.com?

Tags: validation, salesforce

I need a validation rule that prevents certain users from editing the OpportunityLineItem records.

I'm assuming that I will need to compare the LastModifiedDate value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Friday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the special fields available in formulas that begin with dollar sign. Roughly speaking they depend on who is looking at the data and aren't related to the record itself. They contain basic running user's info, his session id etc.

Example validation rule could look like that:

```
OR($Profile.Name = 'Marketing User',
$UserRole.Name = 'IT',
$User.Title = 'Contractor'
)
```

This should get you started if you can easily distinguish your "certain users" by Role, Profile or for example some checkbox you'd put on the User record that would be editable only by sysadmins.

If your logic is more complex (dependent on being a member of some group for example) - you'll have to write a trigger I believe.

---

Keep in mind that validation rules don't fire on record delete! If this is a concern there are 2 ways to solve it:

- sane way: to remove the right to delete Opportunities (because Opp. Products "inherit" this permission from Opportunities) from most Profiles and then apply it to selected users with Permission Set
- hacky way: delete of product will cause some rollup recalculations on the Opportunity (for example Amount field). So build a similar rule to the one you'll have on Opp. Line Items and attach `&& ISCHANGED(Amount)` to it.